# iOS: Play/Stop music in Background at a specific time

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, background, ipod

I am developing an app which can stop or play a music from iPod or other audio at a specific time even if is in background. Is it possible?

I know that with a local notification can play an audio during 30 seconds, but I need more time. There are application which can do this like TuneIn Radio.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Just wondering if you ended up finding a solution to this

Comment: If someone else is wondering about the same problem, I ended up using AVQueuePlayer, then using addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval, and a silent sound files, I can effectively stop and start at any required time (in reality I'm just replaying the silent sound until a set time). It's a hack but it'll do for my purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Unless it is your app that is playing the music in the background I don't think it is going to be possible. The hardest part is the fact that you can't run an app in the background unless it is playsound, keeping track of the users location or is a voip client.

You can use a local notification, but the allarm sound is restricted to the 30 seconds and you can only stop any audio session if you app gets launched.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! There are application which can do this like TuneIn Radio, but I don't know how. We will continue investigating.